# XmlPullParserException when using SAP WSDL WebService

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2, saprfc

I'm desperately searching for the cause of this XmlPullParserException in KSOAP2-Android.

Here is the code:

```
            String NAMESPACE = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";
            String METHOD_NAME = "ZFanTestWs";
            String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "/" + METHOD_NAME;
            String URL = "http://xxxx.xxx.xx:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/bndg_xxx/wsdl11/allinone/standard/rpc?sap-client=xxx";
            
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("arg0");
            pi.setValue(42);
            pi.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);
            request.addProperty(pi);
            
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

            try
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                result = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The exception occurs on "androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);"

The responeDump of the HttpTransportSE looks exactly like my generated WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"><wsdl:documentation><sidl:sidl/></wsdl:documentation><wsdl:types><xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"><xsd:element name="ZFanTestWs"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="IvImporting" type="xsd:int"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="ZFanTestWsResponse"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="EvExporting" type="xsd:int"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element></xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="ZFanTestWs"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZFanTestWs"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="ZFanTestWsResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:ZFanTestWsResponse"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="Z_FAN_TEST_WS"><wsdl:operation name="ZFanTestWs"><wsdl:input message="tns:ZFanTestWs"/><wsdl:output message="tns:ZFanTestWsResponse"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="DEFAULT" type="tns:Z_FAN_TEST_WS"><soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/><wsdl:operation name="ZFanTestWs"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/><wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="Z_FAN_TEST_WS"><wsdl:port name="DEFAULT" binding="tns:DEFAULT"><soap:address location="http://xxxx.xxx.xx:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_fan_test_ws/xxx/z_fan_test_ws/default"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

It takes an integer as a parameter and returns it.
Are my NAMESPACE and SOAP_ACTION strings correct?
Please share your ideas. Thanks.

edit: stack trace

```
01-17 10:12:11.090: W/System.err(555): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>@1:429 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41076710) 
01-17 10:12:11.180: W/System.err(555):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
01-17 10:12:11.190: W/System.err(555):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
01-17 10:12:11.210: W/System.err(555):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
01-17 10:12:11.221: W/System.err(555):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
01-17 10:12:11.241: W/System.err(555):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
01-17 10:12:11.260: W/System.err(555):  at webservice.test.WebServiceTestActivity$ServiceCall.doInBackground(WebServiceTestActivity.java:111)
01-17 10:12:11.281: W/System.err(555):  at webservice.test.WebServiceTestActivity$ServiceCall.doInBackground(WebServiceTestActivity.java:1)
01-17 10:12:11.292: W/System.err(555):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-17 10:12:11.310: W/System.err(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-17 10:12:11.331: W/System.err(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-17 10:12:11.340: W/System.err(555):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-17 10:12:11.361: W/System.err(555):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-17 10:12:11.371: W/System.err(555):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-17 10:12:11.390: W/System.err(555):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: the stack trace of the exception will tell you..

Comment: Unfortunately, the stack trace isn't very helpful - I've added it above.
It somehow doesn't see a start tag in the correctly recieved WSDL.

Comment: You will have to debug into it and see what is going on. It probably is out of order or something and gets all mixed up. The one thing that makes me think you are doing something wrong is that the response looks like a wsdl.. and it should NOT..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've provided the URL of the WSDL file to KSOAP, which is completely wrong.
You have to supply to URL of the SOAP service itself, which is listed in the WSDL file:

```
<soap:address location="http://xxxx.xxx.xx:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z_fan_test_ws/xxx/z_fan_test_ws/default"/>
```

String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "/" + METHOD_NAME;
works fine in my case.

Thanks Manfred Moser and JPriest for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Your soapaction should an empty string, as follow:

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "";
```