# Android : Ksoap2 org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException

Tags: android, xml-parsing, wsdl, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am new in using KSOAP2 with android and im having  aproblem

i have seen similar posts regarding the same issue but none helped me with my error

I am trying to connect to a web service (WSDL) that returns the username i am logged in with. 
When i open the web service URL in any browser, it first asks for username and password then it returns this username to me, in the code im not sure how do i send this username and password. i want help in this too

below is my code :

```
package com.example.webservicetest;


import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class AndroidWSClientActivity extends Activity {

    static final int CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "MeGetCurrentUserId";

    private static final String WSDL_URL = "http://IP:8010/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_000C293D85161ED39484844BDA759A86/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=200&sap-user=*********&sap-password=********";
private static final String WS_NAMESPACE = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";

private static final String WS_METHOD_NAME = "MeGetCurrentUserId";
private static final String soapAction = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style:ZUSER_ID:MeGetCurrentUserIdRequest";//"urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style:ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID3:MeGetCurrentUserIdRequest";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_wsclient);

        new GetUserNameTask().execute();


    }

    private String parseSOAPResponse(SoapObject response) {
        String result = null;
        SoapObject usernameResult  = (SoapObject) response
                .getProperty("MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse");
        if (usernameResult != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < usernameResult  .getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                SoapObject unameDescription = (SoapObject) usernameResult
                        .getProperty(i);
                String Username = unameDescription
                        .getPrimitivePropertySafelyAsString("Username");

                Log.i(TAG, Username);
                result = Username;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private class GetUserNameTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog(CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result=null;
            final String str = null;
            try {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WS_NAMESPACE, WS_METHOD_NAME);

            MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENV;
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);

            mbase.register(envelope);

            androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);

            Log.d(TAG, "HTTP REQUEST:\n" + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d(TAG, "HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

            final  SoapPrimitive resp = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

            Log.d(TAG, "HTTP resp:\n" + resp);

            Object resonse=envelope.getResponse();

            String output = resonse.toString();
                if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) { // SoapObject = SUCCESS
                    SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    result = parseSOAPResponse(soapObject);
                    Log.v("result", "result = "+result);

                } else if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) { // SoapFault =               // FAILURE
                    SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
                    try {
                        throw new Exception(soapFault.getMessage());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            removeDialog(CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {
        case CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG: {
            ProgressDialog loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            loadingDialog.setMessage("Connecting");
            loadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
            return loadingDialog;
        }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I get the following error :

```
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>@1:687 in java.io.InputStreamReader@408e2840) 
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2037)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:128)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:197)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at com.example.webservicetest.AndroidWSClientActivity$GetUserNameTask.doInBackground(AndroidWSClientActivity.java:95)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at com.example.webservicetest.AndroidWSClientActivity$GetUserNameTask.doInBackground(AndroidWSClientActivity.java:1)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
11-19 15:30:46.520: W/System.err(29600):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

the error is in this line

```
httpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
```

here's my WSDL

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<wsdl:documentation>
<sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl"/>
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN_BN_ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" wsp:Optional="true"/>
<saptrnbnd:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" wsp:Optional="true"/>
<wsp:ExactlyOne xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
<wsp:All>
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpsToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:HttpsToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" wsp:Optional="true"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BN_BN_ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID_SOAP12">
<saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/" uri="http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml" wsp:Optional="true"/>
<saptrnbnd:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" wsp:Optional="true"/>
<wsp:ExactlyOne xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
<wsp:All>
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sapsp="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/security/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:TransportToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpsToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:HttpsToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" wsp:Optional="true"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF_IF_zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<sapsession:Session xmlns:sapsession="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
<sapsession:enableSession>false</sapsession:enableSession>
</sapsession:Session>
<sapcentraladmin:CentralAdministration xmlns:sapcentraladmin="http://www.sap.com/webas/700/soap/features/CentralAdministration/" wsp:Optional="true">
<sapcentraladmin:BusinessApplicationID>000C293D85161EE392C16B764ABA0F3C</sapcentraladmin:BusinessApplicationID>
</sapcentraladmin:CentralAdministration>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_IF_OP_MeGetCurrentUserId">
<sapcomhnd:enableCommit xmlns:sapcomhnd="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/commit/">false</sapcomhnd:enableCommit>
<sapblock:enableBlocking xmlns:sapblock="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/blocking/">true</sapblock:enableBlocking>
<saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required>
<saprmnw05:enableWSRM xmlns:saprmnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/wsrm/">false</saprmnw05:enableWSRM>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
<xsd:simpleType name="char12">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<xsd:import namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"/>
<xsd:element name="MeGetCurrentUserId">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Username" type="n0:char12"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="MeGetCurrentUserId">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MeGetCurrentUserId"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<wsdl:documentation>
<sapdoc:sapdoc xmlns:sapdoc="urn:sap:esi:documentation">
<sapdoc:docitem docURL="http://edr-aioexp.edraky.local:8010/sap/bc/esdt/docu/sd_text?sap-client=200&sd_name=ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID"/>
</sapdoc:sapdoc>
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#IF_IF_zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:operation name="MeGetCurrentUserId">
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_IF_OP_MeGetCurrentUserId"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:input message="tns:MeGetCurrentUserId"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID" type="tns:zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN_BN_ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="MeGetCurrentUserId">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style:zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID:MeGetCurrentUserIdRequest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID_SOAP12" type="tns:zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<wsp:Policy>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BN_BN_ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID_SOAP12"/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsoap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="MeGetCurrentUserId">
<wsoap12:operation soapAction="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style:zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID:MeGetCurrentUserIdRequest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<wsoap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<wsoap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<wsdl:port name="ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID" binding="tns:ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID">
<soap:address location="http://edr-aioexp.edraky.local:8010/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zme_get_current_user_id/200/zme_get_current_user_id/zme_get_current_user_id"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID_SOAP12" binding="tns:ZME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID_SOAP12">
<wsoap12:address location="http://edr-aioexp.edraky.local:8010/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zme_get_current_user_id/200/zme_get_current_user_id/zme_get_current_user_id"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

knowing that we mapped the IP `edr-aioexp.edraky.local` to real ip that i am using in my URL

can anyone help me please ?

**EDIT**

I am not getting this response from ANDROID,

this web service exists on SAP system . when tested on the SAP system, this response appears, but on android i receive no response.

REQUEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<sapsess:Session xmlns:sapsess="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
<enableSession>true</enableSession>
</sapsess:Session>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:MeGetCurrentUserId xmlns:ns1='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>
</ns1:MeGetCurrentUserId>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
<n0:MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<Username>EAB_SAMIR</Username>
</n0:MeGetCurrentUserIdResponse>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post [XmlPullParserException when using SAP WSDL WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882963/xmlpullparserexception-when-using-sap-wsdl-webservice)

helped me solve my problem

my problem was with the `soapAction` and `WSDL_URL`

I used the URL in the WSDL file itself instead of the URL i write in the browser : find the write code below

```
private static final String soapAction = WS_NAMESPACE + "/" + WS_METHOD_NAME; 

private static final String WSDL_URL = "http://IP:8010/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zme_get_current_user_id3/200/zme_get_current_user_id3/zme_get_current_user_id3?sap-user=******&sap-password=******";
```

and i got the response correctly.

Thanks alot to everyone helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You have the error

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG
```

this means you probably have an error in one (or more) of: WSDL_URL, WS_NAMESPACE,WS_METHOD_NAME,.

Try putting :

```
WS_NAMESPACE="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"
soapAction= "zME_GET_CURRENT_USER_ID"
```

Do you still get that error?

Comment: Dear shadesco,



thanks for your help but i still get the same error :(

i will try all combinations of WSDL_URL, WS_NAMESPACE,WS_METHOD_NAME

Comment: @RanaOsama the EDIT that you added, this is from requestDump and responseDump? or how it SHOULD be?

Comment: I edited the WSDL_URL, WS_NAMESPACE,WS_METHOD_NAME 

and i displayed the request and response

Comment: @RanaOsama so after changing these attributes; now you don't have the "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG" error anymore?

Comment: i know the error is in those fields WSDL_URL, WS_NAMESPACE,WS_METHOD_NAME . . . but i cant get the right values of them

Comment: @RanaOsama here is what is confusing me, are you getting a response ? the response you posted in EDIT, it is what you are getting through android? if YES, then it means the error is probably in parsing the response. Maybe your web service is not sending an accurately tagged SOAP envelope structure.

Comment: I am not getting this response from ANDROID,

this web service exists on SAP system . when tested on the SAP system, this response appears, but on android i receive no response.

Comment: @RanaOsama check the following see if it helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882963/xmlpullparserexception-when-using-sap-wsdl-webservice . you have to add a "/" in soapaction -> SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "/" + METHOD_NAME;

Answer (score 0):

```
 check this you have to use request.addProperty() for sending parameter


SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


request.addProperty("User Name", MYUSERNAME);
                request.addProperty("username", MYUSERNAME);
                request.addProperty("Password", MYPASSWORD);

   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        Object resonse=envelope.getResponse();
                      String output = resonse.toString();
```

Comment: Dear Pavan, 

in my code i am already using `request.addProperty` for sending username and password

this is not my issue

Comment: @RanaOsama, I have a problem similar to yours, can you help me?

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira what exactly is your issue ?